# How to transform map into vector using transform function template

Tags: c++, stl

I want to transform a map into vector.

```
int main()
{
    map <int,int> m;
    m[0]=99;
    m[1]=5;

    vector<int> v;
    transform( m.begin(), m.end(), back_inserter( v ), ??? );
}
```

Which function i can use from STL in place of ???. I did a lot of googling, but didnt find out any.

Any discussion will be helpful.

Comment: Are the keys sequential integers? If so, why is that a map to start off with?

Comment: No. Its not sequential. Just to make the example understandable to every one, i have given simplified version of code.

Comment: SGI's implementation of standard library has got [`select1st` and `select2nd`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/select1st.html). They're not in C++ standard, though.

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?  The answers so far are for getting just the values for those elements in the map, ignoring the keys.  Is that what you want, or do you want the keys to be used in the result in some way?

Comment: The map contains *pairs* of integers and booleans. A vector can only contain one type. Do you want a vector containing just the ints? Just the bools? `std::pair<int, bool>`? Something else? And does it matter in which order the elements are inserted into the vector?

Comment: This is a bad example because of vector<bool>. I will edit the question to use vector<int>. That will now make the answers not accurate because they use bool, but none of those who answered seemed to notice the vector<bool> problem.

Answer (score 2):

Either with a lambda:

```
transform(m.begin(), m.end(), back_inserter(v),
         [](pair<const int, bool> const & p) { return p.second; });
```

Or with a simple loop:

```
for (const auto & p : m) { v.push_back(p.second); }
```

Or with an old-style loop:

```
for (map<int, bool>::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
{ v.push_back(it->second); }
```

In any case, call `v.reserve(m.size())` beforehand to avoid reallocations.

Comment: Wouldn't you loose all the keys?

Comment: But according to a comment, the keys are not sequential integers. So what you put in the `vector` looses its meaning.

Comment: @HAL: I really don't care. That's what the OP has asked for, and without more specific requirements (like `m[i] == v[i]` for all `i`) I don't see the need to elaborate. Feel free to write an alternative answer.

Comment: The whole exercise is futile without preserving the keys here but sometimes you don't understand the consequence until pointed out. It would make more sense to store both key and value as `std::pair` in the `std::vector`.

Comment: @HAL: OP also states that this is a simplified example, so we can't assume anything as to the meaning of the keys/values. For all we know, in his code they are completely different types than the ones showed here.

Comment: Actually, both of our answers are wrong. I corrected my answer. You should use type pair<const int, bool>, not pair<int, const bool>, because it is the key that is constant, not the value.

Comment: Why not just use map's value_type and avoid all confusion in the first place?

Comment: 4: Or with a `transform` and a functor, for those old-schoolers still on C++03 (like me).

Comment: bstamour, yes, that'd be way better, in case author initially typedefed his map.

Comment: @JohnDibling: How does that save you? By using templates? Wait for C++14 with polymorphic lambdas...

Comment: It saves my having to write a loop.

Comment: @JohnDibling: As much as I like generic algorithms, I yet have to see a solution that I would like better than the range-based `for` loop. I know it's a loop, but it's also extremely short and easy to read.

Comment: I agree. Only problem is its not possible in C++03.  There the only options are transform+functor or hand written loop.

Comment: @JohnDibling: The benefit of using a functor is that you can make the operator a template, and thus spare yourself having to figure out the correct type. And it's even vaguely reusable.

Comment: So are we not in agreement here?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can store the `bool` values in a `std::vector` at the *unsequential* indexes used as keys in the `std::map` (sort of like a hash bucket).

```
std::vector<bool> v(m.rbegin()->first + 1, false);
for (auto& p : m) {
    v[p.first] = p.second;
}
```

The `std::vector` will be initialized with as many (false) values so that the biggest key number in the `std::map` will fit. The smallest number used as key must be greater or equal to zero.

**Live example:** http://ideone.com/5VQFmr

Comment: `m[INT_MAX] = true;` :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Not the most memory conservative way of storing values, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose here's what you need (in C++11):

```
auto transformer = [] (const pair<const int, bool>& value) {
  return value.second;
};

transform( m.begin(), m.end(), back_inserter( v ), transformer);
```

You can avoid C++11 lambda's if you want writing your own functor class, but the argument of operator() should be the same.

**UPD.** My original answer was wrong, because I wrote pair<int, bool> instead of pair<const int, bool>. This mistake shows importance of typedefs: if you used

```
typedef map<int, bool> MyMapT;
```

instead of plain map definition, you could write the type as MyMapT::value_type. It is way easier to understand and prevents you from making unnecessary temporaries as I did before.

Comment: To be clear, it's not that the original type was outright wrong, but it silently caused a temporary copy of the pair to be created. It would still compile and behave as expected, just less efficiently than necessary.